# mysql_fetch_row while loop not getting all rows

Tags: php

I am writing a program to send sms through XML API. I need to send same message to multiple numbers as well as different message to different numbers in single XML Post. My script is sending sms to multiple number with same message but fails to add different message.

My Table as follows:

mysql> select * from obox;

```
+----+-------+--------+------------+----------+-----+------------+----------+--------+-------+
| id | sid   | sender | pick_time  | del_time | ref | pno        | msg      | report | route |
+----+-------+--------+------------+----------+-----+------------+----------+--------+-------+
|  1 | 10000 | ALERTS | 1414478267 |        9 | 0   | 9XXXXXXXX | test sms  |        |    29 |
|  2 | 10000 | ALERTS | 1414478267 |        9 | 0   | 8XXXXXXXX | tesr sms  |        |    29 |
|  3 | 10000 | ALERTS | 1414478267 |        9 | 0   | 7XXXXXXXX | tesr sms  |        |    29 |
+----+-------+--------+------------+----------+-----+------------+----------+--------+-------+
```

My Script:

```
//geting msg
$content=mysql_query("select msg from obox where pick_time < '$t' and del_time < 100 group by msg", $db) or die(mysql_error());

//getting msg count
$num= mysql_num_rows($content);

//getting loop for each msg type
for($ctr=0; $ctr < $num; $ctr++){

$inctr=1;

while($row=mysql_fetch_row($content)){
$msg=$row[$ctr];

$xml_data ='<MESSAGE VER="1.2">'.
'<USER USERNAME="xxxxx" PASSWORD="xxxxx" DLR="0"/>';

//For each msg, get sender & pno 
$result = mysql_query("select pno, sender from obox where msg='$msg' and pick_time < '$t' and del_time < 100", $db)  or die(mysql_error());

$xml_data .= "<SMS TEXT='$msg' ID='$inctr'>";
$i= 1;
while($row1= mysql_fetch_row($result)){
$pno=$row1[0];
$sender=$row1[1];

$xml_data .= "<ADDRESS FROM='$sender' TO='91$pno' SEQ='$i'/>";
$i++;
}
$xml_data .= "</SMS>";
```

//geting msg Query Output

mysql> select msg from obox where pick_time < '1414748869' and del_time < 100 group by msg

```
+----------+
| msg      |
+----------+
| tesr sms |
| test sms |
+----------+
```

// Script Output

```
<MESSAGE VER="1.2"><USER USERNAME="xxxx" PASSWORD="xxxx" DLR="0"/>
<SMS TEXT='test sms' ID='1'>
<ADDRESS FROM='ALERTS' TO='919xxxxxxxxx' SEQ='1'/></SMS>
</MESSAGE>
```

//Output Should be

```
<MESSAGE VER="1.2"><USER USERNAME="xxxx" PASSWORD="xxxx" DLR="0"/>
<SMS TEXT='test sms' ID='1'>
<ADDRESS FROM='ALERTS' TO='919xxxxxxxxx' SEQ='1'/>
</SMS>
<SMS TEXT='tesr sms' ID='2'>
<ADDRESS FROM='ALERTS' TO='918xxxxxxxxx' SEQ='1'/>
<ADDRESS FROM='ALERTS' TO='917xxxxxxxxx' SEQ='2'/>
</SMS>
</MESSAGE>
```

Pls help. Thanks in Advance.

Regards

PB

Comment: Be aware that this mysql_* library [is deprecated since php 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Think about using mysqli or pdo.

Comment: STOP! Don't write another line of code. `mysql_*` is deprecated, and has been for some time. Start again, using its replacement extensions (either `PDO` or `mysqli_*`)

Answer (score 2):

You have limit 1 in your query. Remove it.

```
$content=mysql_query("select msg from obox where pick_time < '$t' and del_time < 100 group by msg", $db) or die(mysql_error());
```

**EDIT**

You are trying to access $row[1] when $ctr=1 on the second loop when it should be just $row[0]; Change

```
$msg=$row[$ctr];
```

to

```
$msg=$row[0];
```

and remove the for loop if you need it.

**EDIT2**

Your $xml_data is being overwritten on this line.

```
$xml_data ='<MESSAGE VER="1.2">'.
'<USER USERNAME="xxxxx" PASSWORD="xxxxx" DLR="0"/>';
```

I would initialize it before the first while loop and concatenate to it after

```
$xml_data ='';
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($content)){
.
.
.
$xml_data .='<MESSAGE VER="1.2">'.
'<USER USERNAME="xxxxx" PASSWORD="xxxxx" DLR="0"/>';
```

Comment: Does $num equal 1, 2 or 3?

Comment: Not sure why $num equals 2 when it should be 1 since 'test sms' is the only result unless there is a hidden space somewhere.

Comment: $num is equal to 2 but I want both test sms & tesr sms to be included

Comment: Whoops didn't see test sms and tesr sms are different.

Comment: Even then I am getting same output as before. Only last row is reflecting. 1st row tesr sms is still missing

Comment: no change. Output still same which I was getting before

Comment: Maybe initialize the $xml_data outside the for loop if you didn't remove that.

Comment: yes, I have done both way. 1st remove for loop and secondly, outside loop but output remain same

Comment: Not sure what is the issue and running out of ideas... Let's see if you actually retrieve the tesr sms info. Can you attach and msg='tesr sms' to the first query and see if it actually shows?

Comment: Hi, Tks for you support. Problem Solved. $xml_data ='<MESSAGE VER="1.2">'.
'<USER USERNAME="xxxxx" PASSWORD="xxxxx" DLR="0"/>'; to be placed before starting loop.